# how to connect s3 file without access key details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, ssh

We have one unix machine where we have direct access to our s3 bucket. We are able to run all cli commands like "aws s3 ls" from unix machine.
Now we need to read a file from there and create a spark data frame using pyspark.

So now need to do ssh connection to that unix box and read that file and create a spark data frame.

could anyone help how we can access s3 without access key details using pyspark.

Comment: The first part of your Question talks about retrieving a file from a "unix machine" via an SSH connection. But the last sentence asks about accessing S3 without an access key. Which of these two (quite different) things are you wanting to do?

Comment: I need to do both. without downloading the file from S3 I need to create a spark data frame. So thought of accessing directly like below from my unix box after ssh connection (thought unix has direct access to S3, so it will work). But its not working.  `data="s3a://s3databucket/input/test.csv"
df=spark.read.format('csv').option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load(data)`

Comment: Unix box is our EC2 instance. So now i need to asses the s3 file through my EC2 instance using IAM role and create spark data frame

Answer (score 0):

1. The AWS SDK includes a credential provider `com.amazonaws.auth.ProcessCredentialsProvider` which can execute a command and parse the json result. If you can get the s3a connector to instantiate that (you will need to write some java wrapper to read some options like the command to execute),  then you could SSH to the remote host, get its session keys (left as an exercise) then print the output as json it could parse it.
2. before you launch your app, run some script to SSH in, collect the credentials, and set the relevant fs.s3a propoerties.

#2 is clearly the easiest, only try #1 if you want to support long lived processes. If you implement #1, it would actually be a nice contribution to the hadoop-aws codebase...